# How would I get the info of a particular type of objects in a particular trigger in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers

I want to change a thing based on the number of players of each teams in a trigger.

I'm thinking of getting the info of all the objects in the trigger access their tags and identify how many players of each teams are present in that trigger. But I can't find anything to do this.

Comment: well thats all the part of the design now isnt it? your pickups should either descend from a common class, share an interface, or, you write a lot of spagetti, either way your player triggers it, and you react

Answer (score 0):

Init team counts as 0:

```
int team1 = 0;
int team2 = 0;
```

Increase/decrease team count on trigger callbacks. Here you can use tags or whatever you prefer. I recommend having the team information in a script:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Player player = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>();
    if(player == null) return;
    if(player.team == 1) team1++;
    else team2++;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    Player player = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>();
    if(player == null) return;
    if(player.team == 1) team1--;
    else team2--;
}
```

And lastly, do what you want with your team counts:

```
void Update(){
    //use team1 and team2 the way you want
}
```